# Initialize vuex store data at startup in a Vue-Electron App using v-model

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I'm trying too build my first `electron-vue` app. For my state data I'm using `vuex`.

I'm using two-way-binding for a few `bootstrap-vue` forms. At the start of the program I want to initialize the values of these forms to defaults either form program logic or to values read from a config file. But here I'm struggle with my code. The store data is updated (in my example set to true) but not the b-form-checkbox which stays unchecked. I just don't understand why?

Here is my code, for the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-checkbox
      v-model="saveOriginalImage"
    > Save Original Image
    </b-form-checkbox>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    computed: {
        saveOriginalImage: {
        get() {
          return this.$store.getters.GET_SAVE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE;
        },
        set(value) {
          this.$store.dispatch('setSaveOriginalImage', value);
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

My store.js

```
const state = {
  SaveOriginalImage: false,
}

const getters = {
  GET_SAVE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE: state => {
    return state.SaveOriginalImage;
  },

const mutations = {
  SET_SAVE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE (state, payload) {
    state.SaveOriginalImage = payload;
  },
}

const actions = {
  init ({ commit }) {
    commit('SET_SAVE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE', true);
  },

  setSaveOriginalImage ({ commit }, payload) {
    console.log("Action: setSaveOriginalImage payload = " + payload)
    commit('SET_SAVE_ORIGINAL_IMAGE', payload)
  },
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

I'm initializing the store data on the app.on event in my index.js

```
app.on('ready', () => { 
  store.dispatch('init'); 
  createWindow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround using setTimeout:

```
app.on('ready', () => { 
  setTimeout(() => {
    store.dispatch('init'); 
  }, 2500);
  createWindow();
}
```

For me it looks like a timing problem, I've tried `browserWindow` events `ready-to-show`  and a few more to get the right time to call my store init function but with no effect.